# Node JS error while running { PORT=4001 npm run test} this command

Tags: javascript, node.js, port

```
var app= express();
const port=process.env.PORT || 4000;

app.listen(port,function(){
    console.log('Listen on port '+port);
});
```

and when i run this command 
$  `PORT=4001 npm run test`

i am seeing this error

```
PORT=4001 : The term 'PORT=4001' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ PORT=4001 npm run test
+ ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (PORT=4001:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: I think you may need to run as `export PORT=4001`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be running this under PowerShell, but using an example from someone using a Unix/Linux shell.  Make it two commands

```
$Env:PORT = "4001"
npm run test
```